# What do you call the imprinted pattern left behind a car in mud?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, image-identification

What's the name for this ... chase? stria? groove?

In Czech, we call it "stopa" - which literally translates as "footprint" but has a lot of other meanings as well so I can't really work out which of the tons of the English translations I should use here. Trail? Trace? Vestige?

[image: stopa kol]

Comment: Are you looking for something describe the pattern caused by a single vehicle, or the deep grooves caused by many vehicles? For the first, "tyre tracks" as already given is great. For the second I would lean more towards "ruts".

Comment: You can go with just *tracks*, but that doesn't have to be from a car, nor does it have to be in the mud, so you can only use that when those are clear from the context. If not, you'll have to add more to it to specify these factors (if they are relevant).

Comment: EVIDENCE!!!!!!!

Comment: @AndyT He's referring to the word **stopa**, which, as he says, means **footprint**. So I am sure he means the tire print/track mark/tread pattern.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's mostly called a **"tyre tread/track mark"** or a **"tyre tread pattern"**, also a **"tyre track"** and a **"tyre print"**, for instance: ***tyre tread pattern in mud***, ***tyre track mark in mud*** or ***tyre print in mud***

In British English it's "**tyre**", and it's "**tire**" in American English.

Comment: At least in my personal experience (British English native) you are fine just saying "tread mark," most people will understand you are talking about the ruts left by tires.

Comment: Tyre marks, tread marks, and ruts are three completely different things. A rut may or may not be caused by a tyre, and a tread mark may or may not be visible inside a tyre rut. While these are all commonly used interchangeably, and in common speech will generally be understood correctly, they are still distinct from one another, and this is a distinction that is important to make on ELL. See my answer below (http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/126379/36596) for more details.

Answer (score 32):

In AmE, they would be called "tire tracks". Possibly also "tread marks" but that would more likely be used for marks left on a hard surface like concrete or pavement.

Comment: This is a _really_ good answer. I think the best.

Comment: In the southern USA, it would just be "tracks" although anybody would understand what "tire tracks" were. "Tread marks" are where the tread of your tire is left on a surface.

Answer (score 25):

The phrase you are looking for (in BrE at least) is **tread marks**. They can also be called **tyre tracks**.

These are not specific to tread patterns left in mud, but can also be used if a vehicle leaves rubber tyre marks on a hard road.

Comment: Oh, so "tyre" is an adjective in the phrase, thanks

Comment: **tyre** is a noun

Comment: (I think) **tyre tracks** would be a compound noun made up of two nouns.

Comment: "Tire tracks" is also good in the US (spelled tire). I've only heard tread marks used for rubber marks on pavement, though.

Comment: We use 'skid marks' for rubber left on hard surfaces

Comment: @SovereignSun - I thought it was a city...

Answer (score 18):

As a non-native English speaker the first thing that came to mind is [*(mud) ruts*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rut).

**Rut** [ruht] (noun)

- a furrow or track in the ground, especially one made by the passage of a vehicle or vehicles.

Ruts aren't necessarily limited to tyre treads or mud (i.e. ski tracks in the snow would work too), but as far as I'm aware they generally do refer to tracks made by vehicles.

Comment: This is more for the marks left by many vehicles than one vehicle. That may be what OP wants; just clarifying.

Comment: A rut can be left by one vehicle if, for example, it were stuck in the mud and had to be rocked back and forth to get out -- I've left ruts in snow by myself plenty of times, trying to get out of my parking space!

Comment: Perhaps a defining difference between a rut and tire/tread tracks/marks/etc is that a rut is more likely a deep furrow, and may not necessarily have an imprint of the tread in it due to skidding and slippage, while a mark or track will more likely have a tread imprint, and might be very shallow, just barely showing the tread pattern itself, let alone having any "walls" built up along the outsides of the tire path.

Comment: As a native BrEng speaker, I would agree with you.  It does depend on whether the OP mean the grooves in the earth (in which case "rut"), or the details of the tread pattern in the mud (in which case "tyre/tire tracks").

Comment: To my (English) eyes, the OP's **picture** shows *ruts*.  Some of them happen to have *tread marks* (or similar phrases from other answers) in them.  The question **title** fits better with *tread marks*

Answer (score 17):

I'm repeating other the content of other answers, but only because I want to clarify that they are not necessarily correct, depending on *exactly what you're referring to* and *how specific you want to be*:

**A fairly broad answer**

> tread marks

The `tread` of a tyre is the rubber on its circumference that makes contact with the road or the ground - the black bit. You also have a tread on your shoe. Tread marks (also commonly known as *skid marks*, as they are most often caused when vehicles brake hard and skid) are generally the black marks left on the road or elsewhere by tyres (this is the same reason why you're requested not to use black-soled shoes in an indoor gym, so you don't leave tread marks on the gym floor). While it is true that the imprints of the tread are visible in the mud, these aren't tread *marks* in a strict sense.

[image: Tread marks on road surface]

[Example images of tread marks on a road surface, probably skid marks](https://www.google.fi/search?q=tread%20marks%20on%20road&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch).

**A very broad answer**

> ruts

A `rut` is a a long deep track made by the repeated passage of something - most often made by the wheels of vehicles, but can also be made by water flowing downhill, by animals following a game trail, and so on. It is not specific to vehicle wheels.

[image: Vehicle ruts in mud]

[Example image of *vehicle ruts* in mud](http://www.inpoweredtolead.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Rut-muddy-road-e1427799012839.jpg) - note that *tread marks* are sometimes, but not always, visible inside the ruts.

**Probably the least ambiguous answer**

> tyre tracks (US: tire tracks)

To answer the OP's question, the patterns left in mud *specifically* by vehicles would be called *tyre tracks*, which is a fairly literal definition. Although we can distinguish the tread of a tyre from the tyre as a whole, it's a much finer point of semantics as to which made the track in the mud (you could just as well call them *wheel tracks* or *vehicle tracks*, but these phrases are not commonly used and are less accurate).

[image: Tyre tracks in mud]

[Example image of tyre tracks in mud.](http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/d2b5d925186c46479c1241b024f2bc65/tyre-track-marks-in-mud-b8y9rf.jpg)

Comment: First you say **tread marks** is incorrect then you say it's correct, decide already! A rut is a possible word, depending on the OP's request.

Comment: **Skid marks** are left only when the vehicle skids.

Comment: I got caught between drafts. Edited for clarity. Feel free to downvote if it's still crap :)

Comment: `The tread of a tyre is the rubber on its circumference that makes contact with the road or the ground`. That is only the first sentence of the second part of the third entry for _tread_ as a noun. You are purposely omitting the second sentence:  `the pattern of ridges or grooves made or cut in the face of a tire`, as well as the first entry which specifically includes `imprint of a tyre` as the meaning, as well as all the uses of `tread` as a verb which roughly means `to make a path`. `Tread marks` is not synonym to `skid marks`.

Comment: The answer is good, I can't see a reason for a down-vote.

Comment: `Skid marks` are marks made by the `tread` of the tyre when the vehicle skids, no? Tread marks can also be left by means other than skidding, for example when bumping the curbstone with your wheel: http://eastpdxnews.com/images/130712/5-06-BrooksideFatal.jpg

Comment: I agree with walen that the tread is the pattern of raised rubber and indentations used for dispersing water. For example, dry F1 tyres are smooth and have no tread. As such, **tread marks** _may_ be a visible feature of tyre tracks if the ground is soft. Skid marks may show some of the tread pattern, but only the parts that are parallel to the skid direction.

Comment: The first picture is definitely burnout marks, where somebody floored the pedal to spin and squeal the tires. Ah - great days. GREAT days..! :-)

Comment: Seems to me a skid mark would _not_ show the tread.

Comment: Depends whether you think of the tread as the rubber piece around the circumference of the wheel, as mentioned, in which case any tread mark, including a skid mark, is literally the mark of the tread. Or if you're thinking of the tread pattern cut into the rubber, in which case, no, you certainly wouldn't see that in skid marks.

Answer (score 1):

The word "track" is the closest literally to *stopa* -- they both can also mean to follow (as if by following footprints or hoofprints), and both have the secondary sense of a section of music (probably the Czech word is a calque).

As for "rut", that has the meaning closest to the marks showing in your picture, but its secondary meaning, "a fixed routine" especially one you would like to break out of, has grown to overshadow the original use.  Also, there is the fairly rare sense of "to copulate".

So... maybe "tire track".

Comment: "Rut" often refers to a deliberately cut track in the dirt for guiding wheels; a a crude predecessor to the steel rail. That's the source of the metaphor for being "stuck in a rut": like a wheel taking a predetermined path, not able to turn.